# What is the highest number of spell slots a warlock can have?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, warlock, spell-slots

Trying to find out how many spell slots a warlock could have at a given time. Level 20, access to any magic items that can give spell slots, but only one of each (no duplicates), and straight warlock- no multiclassing.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're looking for this? Or something specific you're intending to do with these slots?

Comment: Are you also interested in methods of restoring spent spell slots? This wouldn't make you have more than four at any given time, but you could have more than four spell slots to use between rests. If you are not, then what is the reason you actually need numerous spell spots *simultaneously*? There may be other solutions to the problem besides having more than four available spell spots at once.

Answer (score 3):

#### Four (or 54 depending on how you interpret the Rod of Absorption)

A 20th level warlock has 4 Pact Magic spell slots, and there do not exist any items that give extra spell slots. See [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=spell%20slot&f=equipment,magic-items&c=items) and [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=Spell%20Slots&f=equipment,magic-items&c=items) for DNDBeyond searches that show all items containing "spell slot" and "spell slots".

That said, the Rod of Absorption can *create spell slots within itself*, so I'm not sure if that counts:

> If you are a spellcaster holding the rod, you can convert energy stored in it into spell slots to cast spells you have prepared or know. You can create spell slots only of a level equal to or lower than your own spell slots, up to a maximum of 5th level. You use the stored levels in place of your slots, but otherwise cast the spell as normal. For example, you can use 3 levels stored in the rod as a 3rd-level spell slot.

The energy is stored in the Rod, so technically the Warlock doesn't have those slots, but it can hold the equivalent of 50 1st level spells.

Comment: IIRC the only item-like which grants additional slot is Boon of High Magic, with which warlocks don't apply (as they don't have 9th level slots)

Comment: @Someone_Evil That is correct, "You gain one 9th-level spell slot, provided that you already have one." and the Warlock's 9th level mystic arcanum doesn't count as a spell slot.